# Error with reading CSV files in tensorflow using experimental.make_csv_dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am attempting to use `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` to read a set of large csv files. I am particularly using it because `pandas.read_csv` was constantly giving me memory errors, so tensorflow is much faster at reading my files. My reading code looks like:

```
url_list = ["file_1.csv", "file_2.csv", ... "file_20.csv"]
batch_size = 40000

train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    url_list,
    batch_size,
    label_name = "Outcome",
    shuffle = False,
    num_epochs = 1)
```

The problem is that I have a column "Amount" which is given `int32` dtype based on the reading of the first row. This is problematic because some later values are 2000000000 and need to be stored as `int64`.
How can I specify that the "Amount" column should be interpreted as `int64`? I have tried converting them after reading the files using `tf.cast` :

```
for feature, label in train_dataset:
    tf.cast(feature["Amount"],tf.int64)
```

But I am getting this error: `InvalidArgumentError: Field 6 in record is not a valid int32: 2123456789`

I am aware of the `column_names` and `column_default` arguments for `tf.experimental.make_csv_dataset`, however, I have too many columns. Therefore, specifying them and assigning a "dtype" would be very tedious. I also have a combination of strings, floats and integers, so `tf.experimental.make_csv_dataset` is more convenient for pre-processing the data than using `tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset`, which also requires specifying the column names. How do I get around this?

Comment: I think you just provided yourself the best approach: specify all names and dtypes yourself. By generating it you could alleviate the tedious part.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski but I already mentioned that I have too many columns

Comment: Number of columns isn't an issue if you **generate** the column-dtype combination. That's what I was doing for data sets with 1000+ columns. Typically this would go to a separate Python file that is generated. You'd get the header, infer data types and modify what's needed (your `int64` goes here).

Answer (score 0):

```
column_defaults = [tf.string, tf.int32, tf.int64, tf.float32]
select_columns = ["str_col", "int32_col", "Amount", "Outcome"]
pattern = "file_*.csv"
batch_size = 40000
train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    pattern,
    batch_size,
    label_name = "Outcome",
    shuffle = False,
    num_epochs = 1,
    column_defaults=column_defaults,
    select_columns=select_columns
)
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanations for your answer?

Comment: Yeap, It will be much helpful, if you give some comment and explantations